# Firefox binary issue when deploying Python script to Heroku server

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, heroku, firefox

I am deploying a Python script to Heroku. The Python script includes a Selenium script that uses Firefox. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
def runFirefoxSelenium():
   options = FirefoxOptions()
   options.add_argument('--headless')
   options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
   binary = './bin/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin'
   options.binary_location = binary
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
...
```

In the root directory, I created a folder called bin and dumped the Firefox app into the bin.

When I run the script locally (MacOS), it works perfectly. It is able to find the Firefox binary in within the Firefox.app directory.

However, when I upload it to the Heroku server, I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
```

I tried variations where I only put the firefox binary (called "firefox-bin") in the bin folder, but that doesn't work even locally.

How would you recommend that I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you're not married to Selenium, definitely give Playwright a go instead. It takes care of all the browser installation for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) driver manager to get around that issue:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="firefox", headless=False)
```

(If running on a headless server, be sure to use `headless=True` instead.)

For other [SeleniumBase Syntax Formats](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/syntax_formats.md), you can set the browser to Firefox with a `pytest` command-line option: `pytest --firefox`.